# Using small caps in counters with `amsthm`?

Tags: counters, amsthm, small-caps

I want to use lowercase small caps for all section titles. I also want to use old style figures, and in this case I'm using `mathpazo`. Now, suppose I add an appendix to a document and number theorems using the section number as their counter, as in this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\scshape\lowercase}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\scshape\thesection}[]


\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}


\appendix


\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}


\section{Appendix}

\begin{lem}
Something or other.
\end{lem}



\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

I do not like the result. I want the section counter that's part of the Lemma to also be in lowercase small caps. I've tried adding this:

```
\renewcommand{\thelem}{\textsc{\alph{section}}.\arabic{lem}}
```

but it doesn't work: `\textsc` seems to be just ignored.

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want boldface in the theorem labels for a couple of reasons: one is that's too much, the other is that `mathpazo` hasn't boldface small caps. Since you have small caps in titles it's natural to use it also in theorem labels.

Note that `\lowercase` in `\titleformat` is completely out of place and you also need to do something for unnumbered sections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\numberaftertitle}
\newcommand{\numberaftertitle}[1]{#1\quad\MakeLowercase{\thesection}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\newtheoremstyle{oldstylenumbers}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\scshape} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \MakeLowercase{#2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{oldstylenumbers}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

\section{Work}

\begin{lem}
Something or other.
\end{lem}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{lem}
Something or other.
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want boldface small-caps for the prefix, you have to fake it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\numberaftertitle}
\newcommand{\numberaftertitle}[1]{#1\quad\MakeLowercase{\thesection}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\newtheoremstyle{oldstylenumbers}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \fakescinappendix{#2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fakescinappendix}{m}
 {
  \apc_fakesc:e { #1 }
 }

\bool_new:N \g_apc_appendix_bool
\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{\bool_gset_true:N \g_apc_appendix_bool}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \apc_fakesc:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \g_apc_appendix_bool
   {
    \__apc_appendix_format:w #1 \q_stop
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \apc_fakesc:n { e }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__apc_appendix_format:w #1.#2 \q_stop
 {
  \use:c{check@mathfonts}{\fontsize{\use:c{sf@size}}{0}\selectfont #1}.#2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\theoremstyle{oldstylenumbers}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

\section{Work}

\begin{lem}
Something or other.
\end{lem}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{lem}
Something or other.
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You say it is "completely out of place": is this about good typographic practice or about what's feasible, doable? Agreed that bold and small caps are too much combined... I was trying to please multiple people, unfortunately.

Comment: @apc It’s simply wrong.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm just being dense. Do you mean wrong as in "it's the wrong command for what you want"? Or wrong as in "it's wrong to use lowercase small caps in section titles, whether or not they can implement it"?

Comment: @apc `\lowercase` should not be used in the first place; in the first mandatory argument of `\titleformat` you should only have declarations, which `\lowercase` isn't. The fact that it doesn't raise an error is a bit surprising and depends on the internal implementation of `\titleformat`. Simply, `\lowercase` *doesn't* belong there.

Comment: @apc I added code for faking the small caps A.

Comment: thanks for your help, and for clarifying. I'll need to study your code to better understand it, but it looks like it does what I asked! Quick question: if I have a font that provides bold small caps, would there be a simpler solution? I gather I could get around the need to to use declarations in the third argument of `titleformat` with something like this: `\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\scshape}{}{0pt}{\MakeLowercase{#1}\quad\scshape\thesection}[]`.  But maybe the code you provide is still necessary for using small caps in the theorem label?